# Calling remote REST services from Couchbase Server

Tags: java, couchbase, couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

I am using Couchbase to store data in No SQL format, I would like to know what is the best way to call a REST service to any remote java Application whenever there will be any change in the No SQL doc.

Is there a need to build a plugin or something for the same or there is any better way to do the same.

As I am new to both NoSQL and CouchBase, I would really appreciate some advice.

Looking forward to your answer!

Cheers,